# Where can i find my Model numbers

Tags: updates

Just wondering how do I find which model number my galaxy s4 is? I see people writing Gt- numbers.  I can't find anything like that. Any help would be greatly appreciated Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Note that not all S4 models start with "GT" - see a not-so-complete list of variants [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S4#Model_variants).

You could either see it under Settings - About phone - Model number (in this example, SCH-I545):

[image]

Or on the sticker underneath the battery (in this example, GT-i9505G):

[image]